# Docker Access exposed Port of container via Docker Compose from other container

Tags: docker, docker-network

Hello I am pulling my hair out on this one...

I have a few containers on a machine and I need to access the exposed port of a container from another container, but only the exposed ports are filtered when I checked with nmap.

Putting those 2 containers in the same network is not an option because the container which needs to access the exposed Port is spawned via CI and I can't change that for one niche builder. The registry just happens to run on the same dockerhost as this builder.

Example Setup:

Container 1 with exposed Port

```sh
[~] #  docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 nginx
```

Container 2 which has to access this port

```sh
[~] # docker run -it --rm alpine:3.15
/ # apk add nmap
(7/7) Installing nmap (7.92-r2)
/ # nmap 192.168.1.1
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-05-20 06:53 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.000052s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed tcp ports (reset)
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp   open     ssh
8080/tcp filtered upnp
```

Port 8080 is my target port. Does anyone have an Idea why that port is filtered and how I can open that port?

Best Regards,
bsq

**Edit:**

My problem only exists when I create the exposed port via docker-compose.

Container Nginx 1 Docker Run:

```sh
[~] # docker run -it --rm -p 8081:80 nginx
```

Container Nginx 2 Docker Compose:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
```

Client Host 192.168.1.1:

```sh
curl http://192.168.1.1:8081 # works
curl http://192.168.1.1:8082 # works
```

Client Docker:

```sh
curl http://192.168.1.1:8081 # works
curl http://192.168.1.1:8082 # doesn't work
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.1 port 8082 after 127205 ms: Operation timed out
```

Comment: Who is 192.168.1.1? Is alpine using a bridge network? As seen from container your host is `172.17.0.1` by default or `host.docker.internal` for network `bridge`. You can check by `docker network inspect bridge` (IPAM-Config-Gateway)

Comment: 192.168.1.1 is the server running docker.

But I can ping 192.168.1.1 and I could also ssh from a docker container running on that host to 192.168.1.1:22 if I wanted to, only exposed ports are filtered not ports opened by host services

Comment: Do you have special network settings? Do `docker inspect CONTAINER`, there you see host IP under NetworkSettings-Networks-<networkname>-Gateway.

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but the duplicated `nginx` at the end of your `docker run` command for the nginx container causes the container to exit immediately. You only need `nginx` once.

Comment: The double nginx was a typo.

I noticed I can't access ports exposed via docker-compose. Docker run exposed Ports are accessable without problems.

I am trying to figure out the exact difference.

Comment: The difference is `docker run` joins network `bridge` and `docker-compose up` creates a own bridge-network `projectname_default` by default.

Comment: I kindly advise you to share the `docker network inspect` and `docker inspect container` (network part) results

Comment: @BeyondStupidQuestions did you figure it out?